Tableau progress bar with text status
I'm trying to create a progress bar that shows different activities moving different statuses.  In this case, I working with risk assessments that follow a linear flow from initial review through final validation, 8 steps in total.
What I've done so far is convert the status to a numerical value in order to generate the bar, and this works great in until a point.  The problem here is that what I want to display on the axis is the status, not the value.  I've added images above the chart on the dashboard as a fake header, but it looks really bad when you start filtering the list.  As the scroll bar appears and disappears depending on how many records are shown, the fake header doesn't resize accordingly.
The other thing I've tried is creating a measure for each status so that I can use the axis for the measure.  This creates 16 different calculations though (each measure ends up in a dual axis arrangement).  This gets the look that I want, but it slows down the visualization to the point that no one uses it.
This is what I'm trying to get, but without taking 5 mins to load...


You could likely use reference lines with labels to get the headers you want, or at least a close approximation

Its difficult to help you with your performance question without a little more detail. Can you explain more about your multiple measure, dual axis approach? Showing an example or two could shed light on what you're trying.

I know it's not a great explanation, but what I want is a list of tasks in the rows shelf and a horizontal bar chart for each task.  The values in the chart are a continuous measure that runs from 1 to 8.  Instead of the labels being the values 1 to 8, I want them to have the status name that corresponds to the 1 to 8.

What I have currently is a measure for each status that has a value of -1.5, 0.5, or 1.5 corresponding to whether each task is in a prior status, in the status, or past the status.  For each measure the X axis is 0 to 1, so that it's empty for -1.5, in the middle for 0.5, and a solid line for 1.5.  The dual axis is so that I can have both the bar and the triangle on the end.  One status is a little different, but that's the gist of it

Each column in the picture is a dual axis chart of a bar and a shape.  The problem is that's technically 16 measures times more than 100 tasks.  Once any filtering is applied, it gets really s-l-o-w.

16 measures for 100 tasks should be fast. Something else is going on with your filters. Can you post an example to Tableau Public?

Again, you can use reference lines with labels to show your status names
